# Non-LINQ Array Search

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Is there a non-LINQ way to search an array? The application IDE I am using does not support LINQ.

```
using System.Linq;

string qSupEquip  = "Two";

string [] keyOne = {"ALBAN", "BALYWIN", "BALT"};


private void XtraReportTemplate_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {

    if (keyOne.Contains(lblFac.Text)){
        lblName.Text = qSupEquip;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just write a foreach loop and test the elements one by one

Comment: Does this code do what you want? Anyway it´s not the IDE that doesn´t allow you to use LINQ, it might be the .NET-framework itself. LINQ exists only on .NET 3.5 upwards.

Comment: You could try to use the [`Array.IndexOf<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx) static method.

Comment: `Array.Find Array.FindAll Array.FindIndex Array.IndexOf`

Comment: Well, LINQ has been around for 10 years. Arrays have been around since about the time that any language that uses them was created, so yes, there's a way. :) What have you tried?

Comment: Your code above has a 'Using System.Linq' statement!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just iterate the array and check every item:

```
bool found = false;
foreach(var element in keyOne)
{
    if(element == lblFac.Text)
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternativly make a list out of your array and use `List.Contains`:

```
bool found = new List<string>(keyOne).Contains(lblFac.Text);
```

Answer (score -2):

I try to avoid loops whenever possible, so one of a few methods on System.Array should work for you.  My first choice would be the Exists method since you only really care whether the element is in the array at all.  You could also use Find or IndexOf if you needed to actually access the element or use its value.

```
if(Array.Exists(keyOne, elem => elem == lblFac.Text){
    lblName.Text = qSupEquip;
}
```

Comment: What do you think is happening inside of Array.Exists() when you call it? Because I guarantee it's ultimately looping (if it didn't throw an exception).

Comment: When I said I try to avoid loops, I meant that I usually try to avoid coding my own loops when I don't need to.  They tend to detract from the ability to read and maintain code.

Comment: You said you try to avoid loops whenever possible, then said "so a few methods on System.Array should work for you," then picked a method that looped. My problem is that your comment doesn't reflect the reality of the code. It sounds like it discourages looping, then recommends it. There is nothing inherently wrong with looping, and I find that today's programmers are unaware of the code that they call that actually loops. Looping is a necessity to solve a number of issues and should not be discouraged in a blanket way. It's fine to recommend Exists(). It's not fine to pretend it doesn't loop.